# Extracting Tire Sizes using Regex - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not much familiar with Regex. I need to extract the following patterns that are between () in these sentences:

It is important to note that sometimes there is a white space before the "R" and sometimes not.

```
a) SE NECESITAN LOS SIGUIENTES NEUMATICOS 155/80 R13 PIRELLI FORMULA GT1  (Extract 155/80 R13)
b) REPARACION UTILIZANDO MEDIDA 215/70R16 GOODYEAR  (Extract 215/70R16)
```

I was trying this regular expression, but it fails when there is a white space before the "R" (Example: 155/80 R13).

```
\w*\d\w*\/\w+(?:[\/-]\w+)?(?:\s(?:\d+[A-Z]\w*|[A-Z]{1,2})\b)*
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[0-9]+/[0-9]+\s?R[0-9]+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\d+\/\d+\s?R\d+`

Explanation:

`\d+` - match one or more digits

`\/` - match `/` literally

`\s?` - match zero or one whitespace

`R` - match `R` literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EwVEIj/1)

Comment: Hey, this worked perfectly. Thanks for the explanation too. This is my second question here so I don't know if there's a way to mark the question as solved, but this did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: @CapitanCastor Glad I could help. Green check mark on the left side to the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a more accurate regex pattern if you're matching for **ISO metric tire codes**:

```
(PT|LT|ST|T|)\d{3}\/\d{2,3}\s?(B|D|R|)\d{1,2}
```

Based on explanation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tire_code):

- `(PT|LT|ST|T|)` - An optional letter (or letters) indicating the intended use or vehicle class for the tire
- `\d{3}` - 3-digit number: The "nominal section width" of the tire in millimeters
- `/` - Slash character for character separation.
- `\d{2,3}` - 2- or 3-digit number: The "aspect ratio" of the sidewall height as a percentage of the nominal section width of the tire
- `\s?` - optional space *(not in Wikipedia explanation)*
- `(B|D|R|)` - An optional letter indicating the construction of the fabric carcass of the tire
- `\d{1,2}` - 1- or 2-digit number: Diameter in inches of the wheel that the tires are designed to fit

Limitations:

- Long index and speed rating is not included here but can be easily added

Comment: Adding more to your answer in the following regex load index and speed rating also exists
(PT|LT|ST|T|)\d{3}\/\d{2,3}\s?(B|D|R|)\d{1,2}\s?([6-9][0-9]|[1][0-3][0-9])\s?(A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6|A7|A8|B|C|D|E|F|G|J|K|L|M|N|P|Q|R|S|T|U|H|V|W|Y|\(Y\)|\(W\))?